# How to handle a list to CSV record field in Haskell

Tags: csv, haskell

The goal is to read in a text file and convert it to a csv. The input text file lines will always have some fields, but there will be other fields that appear zero, 1, or more times. The problem is how to handle those fields with varying numbers of items.

Example of the problem:

I can parse the text file to get a list of "events" that might look like the following where each of the data constructors if for a particular type TrialEvents:

For instance,

```
trialRecord1 = [ Trial {time = 123, trialNum = 1}
               , Efix {eye ='R' ,start = 123, stop = 234, x = 222, y = 123}
               , RewStart {time = 234}, RewEnd {time = 345} ]

trialRecord2 = [ Trial {time = 123, trialNum = 1}
               , RewStart {time = 234}, RewEnd {time = 345} ]

trialRecord3 = [ Trial {time = 123, trialNum = 1}
               , Efix {eye ='R' ,start = 123, stop = 234, x = 222, y = 123}
               , Efix {eye ='R' ,start = 223, stop = 334, x = 100, y = 222}
               , RewStart {time = 234}, RewEnd {time = 345} ]
```

These lists of events, one for each trial, will always have a trial number and time, but may have 0, 1, or more of other values, such as `Efix` in this example.

My confusion is about how to generate a csv file from such data where I can have column heads such as trialTime, trialNumber, fixationStartTime, ... , rewStartTime, and RewEndTime. To be able to write the fixationStartTimes I thought I could use a list that could be empty, have one value, or have multiple values.

But when using the cassava package and writing my own instance of `ToField` (just testing with a list of integers) with `pack $ show` I noticed I get quotes and escapes characters when the list is greater than length 1, but not for 1 or zero length lists.

```
"123,234,\"[1,2]\",345,456\r\n"
"123,234,[1],345,456\r\n"
```

This will present problems when I try to read the csv file into an analysis program and I will have to handle these varying cases.

Can anyone advise how I might approach this issue of a variable length list in a conversion to csv and how to make it maximally friendly on reading the CSV into another environment like R?

Thanks.

Comment: Your list has a comma character, so it has to be quoted to keep it from being interpreted as multiple fields. If the quotes are the problem, you could always use a different delimiter inside your list, like spaces or something.

Comment: Thank you. This may be the simplest thing to do, and then I can replace those on the R side with gsub or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anyone advise how I might approach this issue of a variable length list in a conversion to csv and how to make it maximally friendly on reading the CSV into another environment like R?

Since this seems to be the core question, and the remainder of the post seems to be an X-Y problem that assumes CSV as the preferred format, here's an isolated answer to that:

How about using JSON instead? You can write your data type to a JSON structure that is isomorphic to the one you've already got, and R supports JSON through [`jsonlite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html). Then you can have your variable-length lists in R without needing to encode them into a column layout (and back again?).

---

If, however, you'd prefer to *have* that column layout, here's an answer to that:

> events will always have a trial number and time, but may have 0, 1, or more of other values, such as `Efix`*[, `RewStart` and `RewEnd` [?]*] in this example.

Then having

```
data Event = Trial { time :: Int, trialNum :: Int }
           | Efix { eye :: Char, start :: Int, stop :: Int, x :: Int, y :: Int }
           | RewStart { time :: Int }
           | RewEnd { time :: Int }

type Events = [Event]
```

does not seem to quite model what you're saying. How about, instead,

```
data Event p = Trial { time :: Int, trialNum :: Int, points :: [p] }
data Point = Efix { eye :: Char, start :: Int, stop :: Int, x :: Int, y :: Int }
           | RewStart { time :: Int }
           | RewEnd { time :: Int }

type Events = [Event Point]
```

Then your records would look like

```
trialRecord1 = Trial { time = 123, trialNum = 1, points =
                 [ Efix { eye = 'R', start = 123, stop = 234, x = 222, y = 123 }
                 , RewStart { time = 234 }
                 , RewEnd { time = 345 } ] }

trialRecord2 = Trial { time = 123, trialNum = 1, points =
                 [ RewStart { time = 234 }
                 , RewEnd { time = 345 } ] }

trialRecord3 = Trial { time = 123, trialNum = 1, points =
                 [ Efix { eye = 'R', start = 123, stop = 234, x = 222, y = 123 }
                 , Efix { eye = 'R', start = 223, stop = 334, x = 100, y = 222 }
                 , RewStart { time = 234 }
                 , RewEnd { time = 345 } ] }
```

> How do I generate a csv file from such data where I can have column heads such as *trialTime*, *trialNum*, *fixationStartTime*, ..., *rewStartTime*, and *rewEndTime*.

Since you can only be sure of *trialTime* and *trialNum*, those are the only two columns you can hardcode. The rest of the columns have to be indented according to what points are present in the other events. For example, rendering `trialRecord1`, `trialRecord2` and `trialRecord3` in a table layout should (probably?) give something like

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------+------------+---------------+-------------+
| recordNum | trialTime | trialNum | fixationEye1 | fixationStartTime1 | fixationStopTime1 | fixationX1 | fixationY1 | fixationEye2 | fixationStartTime2 | fixationStopTime2 | fixationX2 | fixationY2 | rewStartTime1 | rewEndTime1 |
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------+------------+---------------+-------------+
|         1 |       123 |        1 |            R |                123 |               234 |        222 |        123 |              |                    |                   |            |            |           234 |         345 |
|         2 |       123 |        1 |              |                    |                   |            |            |              |                    |                   |            |            |           234 |         345 |
|         3 |       123 |        1 |            R |                123 |               234 |        222 |        123 |            R |                223 |               334 |        100 |        222 |           234 |         345 |
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------+------------+---------------+-------------+
```

You could write a function `align :: [Event Point] -> [Event (Maybe Point)]` that inserts `Nothing`s in case of missing data points. (A `Nothing` may correspond to a variable amount of rows depending on what `Point` is being translated to columns, so you could also consider a function of type `[Event Point] -> [Event (Either NumEmptyColumns Point)]` where `type NumEmptyColumns = Int`.)

Running `align [ trialRecord1, trialRecord2, trialRecord3 ]` could then give the value

```
[ Trial { time = 123, trialNum = 1, points =
    [ Just $ Efix { eye ='R', start = 123, stop = 234, x = 222, y = 123 }
    , Nothing
    , Just $ RewStart { time = 234 }
    , Just $ RewEnd { time = 345 } ] }

, Trial { time = 123, trialNum = 1, points =
    [ Nothing
    , Nothing
    , Just $ RewStart { time = 234 }
    , Just $ RewEnd { time = 345 } ] }

, Trial { time = 123, trialNum = 1, points =
    [ Just $ Efix { eye ='R', start = 123, stop = 234, x = 222, y = 123 }
    , Just $ Efix { eye ='R', start = 223, stop = 334, x = 100, y = 222 }
    , Just $ RewStart { time = 234 }
    , Just $ RewEnd { time = 345 } ] }
]
```

Turning this regular (non-jagged) list of lists into a regular csv should be more straight-forward.

> with `pack $ show` I noticed I get quotes and escapes characters when the list is greater than length 1
>
> ```
> "123,234,\"[1,2]\",345,456\r\n"
> ```

As @DarthFennec says, this is because the value `[1,2]` contains a comma which is a special character in your csv. The only kind of escape character you have here is the `"`s -- the `\`s are Haskell escape codes to show a string that contains a quote:

```
GHCi> putStrLn "123,234,\"[1,2]\",345,456\r\n"
123,234,"[1,2]",345,456
```

This is how the string actually looks like.

But having multiple values in a Haskell-syntax list literal in a csv file is probably not "maximally friendly". If you're doing that, then perhaps JSON is a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent advice. I will try some of your suggestions and when I get one to work come back and accept the answer.

Comment: I accepted this because of the json advice. I dreaded learning yet another haskell package, but aeson is pretty minimal, and ultimately I was able to write my own toJSON instances for my special data types, and with jsonlite on the R side, it seems a better solution than csv. I hope to come back some day soon and write a more complete version of the solution I used in case it will help someone to see details. If you end up before then, just write me.